# Animating Hiding Subviews in UIStackView goes out of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate the hiding of the arranged subviews of a UIStackView:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0) {
    self.stackView.subviews.forEach({ $0.isHidden = true })
    self.stackView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
} completion: { (_) in
    self.children.forEach({ $0.removeFromParent() })
    completion()
}
```

The problem is the views while animating expand in their width across the screen (out of screen bounds).

This is how the views are setup:

```swift
scrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

stackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return stackView
}()

contentView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

contentView.addSubview(stackView)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
```

Question: How can I animate it in such a way, that it does not change width during the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a weird issue of the `UIStackView` or it serves some purpose, but: putting an "invisible" `UIView` into your `UIStackView` will fix the issue. Tag it, so when hiding the other elements it remains visible:

```
let imposterView = UIView()
imposterView.tag = 999
stackView.addArrangedSubview(imposterView)
```

Of course handle your hiding logic accordingly:

```
stackView.subviews.forEach({
     if $0.tag != 999 {
         $0.isHidden = true
     }
})
```

Comment: This solves the problem of the width changing during animation, thank you very much!